# Automatically fitting markdown images inside a div

Tags: html, css, flask, flask-bootstrap

So I am trying to fit markdown text+image inside a panel. I am integrating [flask blogging extension](https://github.com/gouthambs/Flask-Blogging) into my website. The issue is that this renders the text containing image links and paragraph at once so I cant individually select images to resize them. Is it possible for me to style the div block in such a way that all the text and images fit inside properly. This is how I am rendering atm,

```
<p style="width: 100%">{{ post.rendered_text | safe }}</p>
```

It fits the text okay but the images go out of the div sometimes. I would be grateful if someone could please point me in the right direction.

Code for panel,

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-top: 60px; "> <!-- Blog Post -->
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title">{{ post.title }}</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body" style="width: 100%">
              <p style="width: 100%">{{ post.rendered_text | safe }}</p>         
            </div>

            <div class="panel-footer">Posted by Name on Date</div>

          </div>
```

Comment: Could you add a Snippet or a Fiddle of the part you've worked so far and explain better what results you expect to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

To automatically fit markdown inside a div you need to use [Attribute lists extention](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/attr_list/) from [python-markdown](https://python-markdown.github.io/).

Here is a small example:

1. `main.py`

```py
# We import the markdown library
import markdown
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import Markup

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')

def index():
  content = """
Chapter
=======

![image](https://defenders.org/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/dolphin-kristian-sekulic-isp.jpg){: .rounded-corner}

Section
-------

* Item 1
* Item 2
"""
  content = Markup(markdown.markdown(content, extensions=['markdown.extensions.attr_list']))
  return render_template('index.html', **locals())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='3000')
```

2. `templates/index.html`

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .rounded-corner {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
    </style>
    <title>Markdown Snippet</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{ content }}
  </body>
</html>
```

You need to insert the **class name** after each image you insert with markdown, for example `rounded-corner`:

```py
![image](https://defenders.org/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/dolphin-kristian-sekulic-isp.jpg){: .rounded-corner}
```

The same way you can insert **ids** or **other keys**:

```py
![image](https://defenders.org/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/dolphin-kristian-sekulic-isp.jpg){: #someid alt='dolphin'}
```

And when you transform markdown to html you need to call the extentsion that you need:

```py
  content = Markup(markdown.markdown(content, extensions=['markdown.extensions.attr_list']))
```

To add image inside div you need to use [python-markdown extra](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/extra/)